# GSM modules and ICs

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, gsm

I have been looking for GSM modules and found some very interesting devices, such as the SIMCOM 7100C and similar.

The "problem" I have with these is that they are very high-level, that is, you can directly connect an LCD display or a keypad to it and it even includes some ARM processor.

I have been thinking, the "core" functionality of these modules must be available in some simple integrated circuit. I have on SIMCOM's website that the 7100C is built around Qualcomm MDM9215. But I couldn't find much about it.

- What do I look for (what are these ICs called)?
- How would one go about building a GSM solution such as the SIMCOM's IC?

Thanks!

Comment: It's Qualcomm. They won't tell you anything until you sign a contract to buy a million of them and a NDA.

Comment: I see :(. Any other way to ways to add GSM capabilities to my device other than integrating a device built around a CPU that could fly a rocket to Mars?

Comment: GSM is really complicated and involve licensed technology. These modules exist for a reason. Unless you're going to mass produce something, forget about it.

Comment: I am OK with a black-box, but I would like to get a module that doesn't include tons of other features I don't need. Do you know about anything like that? All the GSM features, but with nice, low-level (non-ASCII) interface?

Comment: Most modules still have a Hayes AT type interface. It can come in handy during development because you can try out the AT commands using just a terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Gemalto (http://www.gemalto.com/m2m/solutions/modules-terminals) and Sierra Wireless (http://www.sierrawireless.com/products-and-solutions/embedded-solutions/).

Do you really need LTE? The modules are about 4x the cost of 2G. That is part of the reason the SIMCOM module is so complex.

Comment: This is very interesting! Thanks, I'll have a look at them. Exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: Just one more question, could one (in principle) base a regular cell phone on Sierra Wireless' HL series chip?

Comment: I've not used the HL so cannot comment on that specific part. I used a 2G Gemalto BGS2W a few months back and that could definitely implement a cell phone, their eval board did exactly that with a headset. Ditto a Sierra Wireless Wismo228 (now obsolete) that I have used. You need to look for analog audio input and output to a microphone and earphone to make things simple. Most 2G modules have analog audio, some 3G modules need an eternal codec to convert analog to digital.